# Approximation problem involving binomial coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, numerical-methods, asymptotics, approximation

Assuming $m=\frac{n}{2\log n}$ for what value of $t$ in $1<t<m$ (close approximation) do we have $$\frac{m}{t}\binom{m}{t}=n 2^{\frac{nt}{2m}}?$$

Also at what minimum values of $n>0$ do such approximations become tight?

Comment: What is the base of the logarithm?

Comment: @KevinCostello natural is fine situation.